# Comparing variables with jQuery

Tags: jquery

## I am using a jQuery library that allows me to retrieve the current song being played in real time from my shoutcast server. I have posted the code below.

```
$(document).ready(
            function() {
                setInterval(function() {
                    console.log("refreshed");
                    var data = "http://live.soundcheck.xyz:8000/playingart?sid=1";
                    $("#albumart").attr("src", data);
                    location.reload();
                    $.SHOUTcast({
                        host : 'live.soundcheck.xyz',
                        port : 8000,
                        interval : 5000,
                    }).stats(function(){
                        $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));
                      var a = $('#songtitle').text(this.get('songtitle'));

                    });
```

The code above puts the "Artist Name - Song Title" into a span element with the class 'songtitle' I've also stored this data into a variable called 'a' This script automatically refreshes at a given interval of 5 seconds.

I need to stored the current song in a variable which has already been done but I need that variable to be permanent once it has been set so I can compare it with another variable that is constantly changing.

I need to know when the current playing song has changed to something else. I need to find a way that I can compare two variables to see if they are equal as in a = b but i only want b to update its value while 'a' would remain.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: Show us what you've tried. Not quite sure how to answer this question. Seems a bit vague.

Comment: One would assume there is kind of an event for the plugin that gets called when the song is changed. Show us some code, creating 2 variables can be as easy as `var t` and `var s`

Answer (score 0):

`var lastKnownSong = null;` at the beginning of your code.

Then, `var currentSong = this.get('songtitle');` in the SHOUTcase callback.

(Protip: Give your variables meaningful names!)

```
if( currentSong != lastKnownSong) {
    // do something! it changed!

    lastKnownSong = currentSong; // update last known song
}
```